# A faster way to separate the green channel of an image

Tags: python, performance, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using the following code, to separate the green channel of an image into a separate .jpeg using PIL and numpy.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('image.jpg')
im = np.array(im)
im[:,:,0] *=0
im[:,:,2] *=0
im = Image.fromarray(im,'RGB')
im.save('greened.jpg')
```

The code works fine, but it takes about a second to execute when put into a loop for a series of images.

Is there any other way to do the same in a faster way?

Comment: Profile your code. What takes the longest time? My guess, `im.save`. If so, no chance to make your code faster.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign zeros in one go and won't even need to multiply by `0` -

```
im[:,:,[0,2]] = 0
```

Comment: Oh, you made the program a half milli second faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use opencv you can speed it up by avoiding construction of numpy array and conversion back to image.

I've tried:

This took `0.011458` second on average(10).

```
@tm_it
def with_PIL():
    im = imag.open('C:/Users/srlatch/Desktop/shi.jpg')
    im = np.array(im)
    im[:,:,0] *=0
    im[:,:,2] *=0
    im = imag.fromarray(im,'RGB')
    im.save('greened.jpg')
```

This took `0.000474981` second on average(10):

```
@tm_it
def with_open_cv():
    image=cv2.imread('C:/Users/srlatch/Desktop/shi.jpg')
    image[:,:,[0,2]] = 0
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```